# 16.04 Network Printer Printing Code

Tags: drivers, 16.04, printing

Im using Ubuntu 16.04 and OKI printer model MB471.

Used the add printer, followed recommended settings, and the test page and every other printing job just comes out as a very long code that went on on countless pages (canceled the print, of course).

Tried using .ppd file from OKI website, and it didn't print anything at all.

any ideas?